# How do I determine what changes an app is making to the system?

Tags: root-access, system

Let me start this question with the specific use case.  I have [Cerberus](https://www.cerberusapp.com/home/en) installed for one purpose - in order to disallow pulling down the notification bar when the phone is locked.  If my phone is stolen, I don't want the thief to be able to enable airplane mode (I use Xposed APM+ to provide a fake Power Off button on the lock screen).  But I'd like to know *how* Cerberus does this - what file(s) is it changing, what system changes are being made?

So my question is this - is there a tool that will let me do an OS snapshot before and after and let me compare the deltas, or monitor the actions that a particular application is doing so that I can write a simple app to do that one thing?  I've used tools on Windows in the past that do this, so I can't imagine it's that difficult - I just don't know where to look.  I have root, so root-only tools are ok.

Comment: google 'dalvik debugging'.

Comment: [How to identify the app/process which re-mounts partitions R/W, creates files and changes file permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214229/218526)