# How to identify the app/process which re-mounts partitions R/W, creates files and changes file permissions?

Tags: file-system, malware, mount, processes, unwanted-files

I have a rooted device, with superuser rights granted to a few apps I trust. I have often found my `/system` or `/vendor` partition mounted read/write, and some files `chmod`ed to `0777`. Similarly directories/files with random names are created/deleted (e.g. `/sdcard/.a03Degpoif`), `.nomedia` files are created inside them to hide their contents from gallery etc.

`logcat`/`dmesg` contains no traces of all this happening in background. This doesn't happen periodically but in a slapdash way, internet connectivity isn't a condition either. I have tried disabling/uninstalling apps, looking for any suspicious processes running, but couldn't identify the culprit(s).

Is there a way to figure out who is doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Note***: Following solution requires a rooted device. Kernel must be built with `AUDIT_WATCH`, preferably `AUDIT_TREE`.

The only good thing Google did was to choose the flexible and configurable Linux kernel for Android, not going for something like a [crippled kernel](http://blog.zorinaq.com/i-contribute-to-the-windows-kernel-we-are-slower-than-other-oper/) and trying to handle everything from userspace, including running a Linux kernel <sup>([1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/shipping-a-linux-kernel-with-windows/))</sup>.

Linux kernel's [Audit System](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security_guide/chap-system_auditing) makes it possible to log any system calls or filesystem changes made by a process. In our case we need to identify the process(es) which are writing to `/sdcard` or `/system` and making syscalls `mount` and `chmod`.

Linux distributions have a service [auditd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/auditd.8.html) which communicates with kernel to get information about security-related events. On Android we have already `logd`, not as configurable as `auditd` but enough for basic monitoring. `logd` mainly covers the functionality of its desktop counterpart [syslogd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/syslogd), but also includes [klogd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/klogd) and partially [auditd](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/logd/README.auditd) to get logs from SELinux subsystem of kernel.

We can add a few more rules using [auditctl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/auditctl.8.html) to also report events we are interested in. You can use `auditctl` from a minimal Linux environment on your Android device, or compile the binary from source code (should be built with [--with-arm](https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-userspace/blob/v2.8.5/configure.ac#L309) / [--with-aarch64](https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-userspace/blob/v2.8.5/configure.ac#L321) whatever your devices' architecture is), or get one pre-compiled [here](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=6006931924117907599).

Now create rules files in `/etc` or wherever you want to:

```
# /etc/audit-start.rules

# enable auditing, won't work in PID namespace
# won't work if permanently disabled with kernel parameter "audit=0"
-e 1

# delete previous rules (though there are none on Android)
-D

# increase the buffers to avoid failure
# no. of event to be queued, waiting for logd to read them
-b 10000

# disable rate limit (msgs/sec) to avoid failure
-r 0

# this determines how long to wait in burst of events
--backlog_wait_time 0

# set failure mode to dmesg
-f 1

# define filesystem rules, whatever file/directory you want to watch
-w /system -p wa -k FILESYSTEM_AUDIT

# define syscall rules, see all syscalls with 'ausyscall --dump' or
# here: github.com/linux-audit/audit-userspace/blob/master/lib/aarch64_table.h
-a always,exit -S fchmod -S fchmodat -k CHMOD_AUDIT
-a always,exit -S mount -k MOUNT_AUDIT
```

```
# /etc/audit-stop.rules

# clear on exit, restore Android default values
-e 0
-D
-b 64
-r 5
--backlog_wait_time 18000
```

Apply rules:

```
~# auditctl -R /etc/audit-start.rules
```

Now make changes; mount `/system` R/W, write/delete something there and change file permissions.

Depending on `logd` configuration, you can get `audit` log in one or more of different logs <sup>([2](https://elinux.org/Android_Logging_System))</sup> including `events` buffer <sup>([3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/logd/README.property#7))</sup> of `logcat` and `main` buffer <sup>([4](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/logd/README.property#6))</sup>:

```
~# logcat -d -b events,main | grep _AUDIT
```

Or in kernel's `printk` buffer <sup>([5](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/logd/README.property#5))</sup> and `logact`'s `kernel` buffer <sup>([6](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/logd/README.property#10))</sup>:

```
~# dmesg | grep _AUDIT
~# logcat -d -b kernel | grep _AUDIT
```

```
audit(0.0:16122): arch=c00000b7 syscall=40 success=yes exit=0 a0=7fcec5db38 a1=7fcec5db3f a2=0 a3=8021 items=1 ppid=761 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="busybox" exe="/data/data/com.mixplorer/files/busybox/busybox" subj=u:r:magisk:s0 key="MOUNT_AUDIT"
audit(0.0:16126): arch=c00000b7 syscall=53 success=yes exit=0 a0=ffffff9c a1=7b839180c0 a2=81a4 a3=0 items=1 ppid=11687 auid=4294967295 uid=10135 gid=10135 euid=10135 suid=10135 fsuid=10135 egid=10135 sgid=10135 fsgid=10135 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="Thread-7" exe="/system/bin/app_process64" subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c135,c256,c512,c768 key="CHMOD_AUDIT"
audit(0.0:16141): arch=c00000b7 syscall=35 success=yes exit=0 a0=ffffff9c a1=7bc22a3c40 a2=0 a3=7bdfbd3098 items=2 ppid=11687 auid=4294967295 uid=10135 gid=10135 euid=10135 suid=10135 fsuid=10135 egid=10135 sgid=10135 fsgid=10135 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="pool-2-thread-1" exe="/system/bin/app_process64" subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c135,c256,c512,c768 key="FILESYSTEM_AUDIT"
```

First line shows that some process running as root with Magisk's SELinux context has made syscall `40` (`mount`) and the command shows it's MiXplorer app (just as example, I did that myself).
Second line indicates that the app running with UID `10135` has `chmod`ed something.
Third line shows the same app (by making syscall `35`) deleted something in `/system` partition.

This is a simple use case. More recursive rules can be defined to deal with complex situations, interpreting other fields of log as well, as explained [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security_guide/app-Audit_Reference#sec-Audit_Events_Fields).

To clear rules:

```
~# auditctl -R /etc/audit-stop.rules
```

**NOTE:**

- For simple cases where the objective is just to get notified of some filesystem changes (and not to trace the originator), `inotify` API can be used instead as explained in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209585/218526).
- In order to mark all the processes that run before the audit starts auditable by kernel, pass `audit=1` boot parameter to kernel, either by editing `cmdline` in `boot.img` or use `fastboot -c` option.
- To save audit log to a file, run `logcat` in background:

  ```
  logcat -s auditd -b events -f /data/media/0/auditd.log &
  ```

Comment: so mixplorer changes /system and /vendor files and creates random folders on /sdcard?

Comment: @alecxs no this was just an example. I did that myself using MiXplorer. I used this method in past to identify some process which were doing something more complex. Simple eample is to make understanding easy.

Comment: Is there a way audit logs be written to the storage instead of remaining in the memory? For example, if I have a directory where random files are being created at random point of time I cannot foresee when they would be created so I would want logs to be stored for a later access despite having a reboot occurred in between this time.

Comment: @Firelord `logcat -s auditd -b events -f /sdcard/auditd.log &`