# Background apps get killed (by something other than battery optimization)

Tags: processes, background-process

All of my background apps get killed when I turn off the screen.
This is particularly annoying for my most-used messaging app, **WhatsApp**.

I've looked at the obvious "Battery Optimization" option: 
[image: battery optimization]

Based on advice found elsewhere, I've checked that the background process limit in developer options is the default (I've never changed this AFAIK):
[image: developer options]

And yet, it gets killed in the same manner as battery optimization would. If I look at running background processes:

[image: before poweroff]

When I then press the power button, and power it back on after < 10s, the list is the same. But if I wait longer than that:

[image: after poweroff]

...whatsapp has disappeared.

This happens for all apps I install that have some sort of useful background feature - the Battery Optimization setting doesn't seem to do its job anymore.

What else can I try to diagnose this?

**NB0**: Android 7.0 on DOOGEE S60

**NB1**: This just started happening some time ago, i.e., it *did* work propertly when I got the phone.

**NB2**: I know how to use `adb`

**NB3**: I'm also fond of trying new apps and have ~400 apps installed. Ideally, I don't uninstall/disable *all* of them 1-by-1 to see which one is the culprit...

Comment: Install Addons Detector or any other similar app and filter to see which apps have permission KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES granted.

Comment: @IrfanLatif hmm only 2 apps show up. 1 is MX Player (presumably because it can make itself the exclusive media player?), the other is Tasker (which I haven't used in ages). Both don't seem likely candidates...Uninstalling them, trying again.

Comment: @IrfanLatif nope, no effect. Whatsapp is still killed. If it makes any difference, most of my widgets (clocks etc.) also stop updating after reboot + screen off...same thing I guess

Comment: Use [this method](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214284/218526) to track `kill` syscall. Requires root.

Comment: ...hmm. It would appear the DOOGEE S60 is not easily rooted. Not without significant effort and wiping the entire phone, that is. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hit and trial. Check `logcat` for any hints why apps killed. Disable doze completely: `dumpsys deviceidle disable all`. Check appops restrictions: `appops get com.whatsapp RUN_IN_BACKGROUND`. Go through related tags, make searches on forums, and try everything possible.

Comment: @IrfanLatif thanks ever so much!

Comment: Welcome and do share if something works for you. Also there are other factors like battery saver, adaptive battery, aggressive battery, background data restriction, power saving mode or any other performance boosting settings. But those might not be directly relevant to your case. And obviously, low hardware resources is an obvious reason for background being killed by Android framework or kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "settings", "memory" and turn off "background auto clean memory".

Comment: Hi, just for confirmation, is this for the device mentioned in the question, Doogee S60? Otherwise, you might want to note the device model since Android is highly customizable, and not every menu is there on every model/version.

Comment: Can confirm; that setting is *not* there on my model...