# Something killing background apps

Tags: 9.0-pie

Just yesterday I bought noname device called `Hisense U30` with Android 9 and it works bad. It killing background apps VERY AGGRESSIVELY. Like I start music in `Yandex.Music` (russian analog Spotify), switch off screen and in 1-2 minutes something kills player. It kills everything.

What I already tried:

1. Disable every preinstalled battery savers;
2. Disable battery optimization for certain apps;
3. Tried everything from [Background apps get killed (by something other than battery optimization)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214639/background-apps-get-killed-by-something-other-than-battery-optimization#comment275009_214639)

Nothing. Player still get killed. OS looks pretty close to stock Android (at least not much preinstalled apps). So my guess is that OS is somehow incorrectly configured.

I looked into `logcat` and what I got:

1. It starts with `MemoryDetectService` like this

```
MemoryDetectService: onStartCommand()---> action = screen_off_app_clear
MemoryDetectService: AutoClearState -----> begin
```

2. Then this service scan through all (I presume) running apps and find mine player too

```
MemoryDetectService: getRunningAppPackageName()---> begin
...
MemoryDetectService: RunningAppProcessInfo: cur.processName = ru.yandex.music:Metrica, pkgName = ru.yandex.music, uid = 10123, uid % 10000 = 123
MemoryDetectService: RunningPkgList---> pkgName = ru.yandex.music
...
MemoryDetectService: getCurrentHomePackages(): recentTasks = ru.yandex.music
```

3. And then, SOMEHOW, decide to kill my player

```
MemoryDetectService: mRunningPkgList: pkgName = ru.yandex.music
MemoryDetectService: mNeedForceStopPkgList---> pkgName = ru.yandex.music
...
MemoryDetectService: currentPkgName---> ru.yandex.music
MemoryDetectService: hasPkgNeedClean(): currentPkgName(New Method: mRecent2PkgList.get(0)) = ru.yandex.music
MemoryDetectService: getWhiteListFromFile: String = null
MemoryDetectService: hasPkgNeedClean(): memBefore = 3894, mWhiteListStr =
```

4. And then it start to kill processes

```
MemoryDetectService: clearMemory-----> begin
MemoryDetectService: clearMemory(): sendBroadcast hmct.intent.action.CLEAR_CACHE: null;
MemoryDetectService: screen on cleaning open = true ,  screen off cleaning open = true
MemoryDetectService: killPackage---> begin
...
MemoryDetectService: forceStopPackage---> begin
MemoryDetectService: clearMemory(forceStopPackage): isScreenOn = false
ActivityManager: Force stopping ru.yandex.music appid=10123 user=0: from pid 1972
ANDR-IOP: IOP HAL: Received pkg_name = ru.yandex.music pid = 0
ActivityManager: kill app.info.packageName=ru.yandex.music minOomAdj=-10000 packageName=ru.yandex.music
ActivityManager: kill app.info.packageName=ru.yandex.music minOomAdj=-10000 packageName=ru.yandex.music
ActivityManager: Killing 6673:ru.yandex.music:Metrica/u0a123 (adj 200): stop ru.yandex.music
ANDR-IOP: IOP HAL: Received pkg_name = ru.yandex.music:Metrica pid = 0
ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service ru.yandex.music/com.yandex.metrica.MetricaService in 20937ms
Zygote  : Process 7489 exited due to signal (9)
...
ActivityManager: Killing 6616:ru.yandex.music/u0a123 (adj 200): stop ru.yandex.music
ANDR-IOP: IOP HAL: Received pkg_name = ru.yandex.music pid = 0
libprocessgroup: kill(-7799, 9) failed: No such process
ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service ru.yandex.music/.common.service.player.MediaSessionService in 20929ms
ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service ru.yandex.music/.common.service.player.AppForegrounderService in 20929ms
...
ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity ActivityRecord{ba18734 u0 ru.yandex.music/.main.MainScreenActivity t248}
MemoryDetectService: setPackageAliveState start----packageName = ru.yandex.music
MemoryDetectService: setPackageAliveState end----packageName = ru.yandex.music, aInfo.processName = ru.yandex.music
MemoryDetectService: mClearAppList---> pkgName = ru.yandex.music, mClearApp++--->1
```

Any idea how to fix this?

P.S. AFAIK there is no other ROM like Linage OS for my phone, and I am not a big fan of `root` cuz this will break Google Pay, so it would be **great** to deal with it without rooting device.

### Update 1

I looked up for this service in `dumpsys`, and I have an idea: disable this service via `adb shell am stopservice com.android.systemui/com.hmct.systemui.taskmanager.detectmemory.MemoryDetectService`. Will be back with results.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have 2G of 4G RAM empty yet my browser is killed every time I switch to any other app. I'm using Xiaomi Lite (supposedly, it should be vanilla android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned, I tried to disable `MemoryDetectService` via `adb` (`adb shell am stopservice com.android.systemui/com.hmct.systemui.taskmanager.detectmemory.MemoryDetectService`), and it looks like it worked. One day, none of my apps is killed while I using them, battery drain is the same (~25% from max yesterday, ~25% today).

From the name of the service I assume that this is service, written by `Hisense` themselves (if they even can modify `SystemUI`).

However, still few concerns:

1. Everything looks fine, but disable some system service is dangerous, so need to be prepared for any s**t;
2. I'm not sure, will this service remain disabled, if I gonna reboot my phone.

Anyway, I will consider this problem solved.

**UPDATE**

Yes, as I expected, this fix is not persist after reboot, but I managed to write bash script and run it manually after each reboot via Termux:

```
#!/bin/bash

am stopservice com.android.systemui/com.hmct.systemui.taskmanager.detectmemory.MemoryDetectService
```