# Purpose of sdcardwritable file

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card

In some directories there's .sdcardwritable file. It's a empty file. What is purpose of this file?

Comment: I don't thing the file is a part of stock Android. Some custom ROM or app must be putting that. If not figured out, there is a slightly hard way to find out who did that: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214284/218526

Comment: I think it's something like `.nomedia` file.

Comment: `.nomedia` is [defined](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/media/libmedia/MediaScanner.cpp#142) in AOSP, `sdcardwritable` isn't.