# Malware downloads APK

Tags: google-play-store, malware

Some app is repeatedly downloading APK files in my Lenovo Android phone.
How can I find which program is doing this ?

I have installed all my apps from Google Play store.

Comment: That must be one of the apps having **Internet** and **Storage** permission. Revoke Storage permission of all such apps (installed by you) one by one and observe. Or block internet connectivity one by one using e.g. VPN firewall, and observe. It's a hit and trial. For a targeted hunt: [How to identify the app/process which creates files?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214284/218526)

Comment: there is a small chance that your device becomes infected with [xhelper malware](https://www.zdnet.com/article/new-unremovable-xhelper-malware-has-infected-45000-android-devices) when your device is Mediatek Chipset [Critical MediaTek rootkit affecting millions of Android devices has been out in the open for months](https://www.xda-developers.com/mediatek-su-rootkit-exploit)