# a process deleted some vital folders and files how do I track it down

Tags: root-access, whatsapp-messenger, data-recovery, partitions, logging

admittedly I am `rooted` on a phone with `unlocked bootloader` & `a Havoc custom  GSI rom  Android 10`
I have hidden `magisk root` from all applications  - every application except the ones that need it  
in spite of this and entire folder on my internal storage - `download` folder as well as `documents` folder - the `document` folder itself was deleted and the `download` folder was emptied completely

I have access to `logcat` and `logcat` does not reveal any information

I regularly run a `malware` check and it comes out ok.

the corresponding data on my external micro SD card is all right

just yesterday `sent` folders of my `WhatsApp image`    (  `/sdcard/WhatsApp/media/WhatsApp Images/sent`   ) directly got emptied without me doing anything. earlier I saw `WhatsApp` 's message that it is backing up my data kind of 40% of 6 GB
and it was taking forever to do that on a 10 MBPS high speed internet connection .  so I stopped the backup process  - but why would it want to delete everything in the sent folder ?
( btw my WhatsApp folder on /sdcard     is `bind mounted` to a special partition on my `micro SD card` which is `ext4` ... now you know why I wanted custom `rom` and `root`   !  )

**here are my questions**  
--- how do I trace back as to what process caused these deletions
--- in the future so as to avoid this or have better traceability what what should I I be installing or modifying or taking as preventive steps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to identify the app/process which re-mounts partitions R/W, creates files and changes file permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214229/how-to-identify-the-app-process-which-re-mounts-partitions-r-w-creates-files-an)

Comment: For simple monitoring of directories you can use inotify tools which are also available for Android.

Comment: It could also be caused by errant Magisk modules. I had a similar experience with Whatsapp and few days later saw others complaining on the module thread. May not be the case with you but just sharing