# Is it possible to find out what apps created a given file/folder?

Tags: file-management, unwanted-files

I want to keep track of the application that created the folder.

I use an Android phone.
And some apps automatically creates unnecessary folders in the root directory of my phone.
I want to know where they come from.(The photo below is an example.)

I can delete that folder but it will be recreated within few minutes.
Are there any apps or adb commands that can monitor whether a folder or file is being edited?
Or, is there a way to block the creation of a folder with the same name?
[image]

I have read all of the guides but may still be wrong. Please tell me if this is a duplicate question. I apologize if this is a bad question.

I want to catch the culprit!

Comment: Hello. Try the answer for the linked question. https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214229/96277

Comment: Some of them are [standard Android folders](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#fields_1): Alarms, DCIM, Documents, Downloads, Movies, Music, Notifications, Pictures, Podcasts, Ringtones, Screenshots.

Comment: @Firelord Thank you! That's exactly what I want.
But my phone doesn't have root privileges, so I have to find another way
(-> I will try to root my spare phone and install all my whole apps.)