# Finding which process writing to storage

Tags: malware, lenovo

I suspect my phone being infected by malware. Every now and then, there's a folder named LSF_PUSH in internal storage, containing APK from app called SnackVideo and other random pictures from its screenshot. I never install this app, but this LSF_PUSH folder keeps created and filled everytime I delete one.
I want to know which process performing this directory creation. How do I find that out?
I've used McAfee and AVG. It doesn't even detect anything.

Comment: Related I guess, about LSF_PUSH: [Lenovo Forums - LSF_PUSH](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/K-P-Vibe/LSF-PUSH/m-p/5054641)

Comment: A related question: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214229/how-to-identify-the-app-process-which-re-mounts-partitions-r-w-creates-files-an

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to identify the app/process which re-mounts partitions R/W, creates files and changes file permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214229/how-to-identify-the-app-process-which-re-mounts-partitions-r-w-creates-files-an)