# How to determine which app or service is frequently writing to storage and causing lagging?

Tags: samsung, internal-storage, performance, lagging, resource-monitoring

When I turn on the screen on a sleeping (but not powered off) high-end Samsung Android 7 Nougat device, the device is often very unresponsive (lagging) for 20-200 seconds.

Using the excellent [Simple System Monitor (SSM)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dp.sysmonitor.app), I can see that it's not a CPU or RAM issue.  There also is only minimal network activity during this time.  The issue appears to be *something* writing to internal storage.  In all the SSM graphs, it's the only graph that shows a high level of activity during the unresponsive period.

How can I determine which process is performing all that writing to internal storage ?  The device is *not* rooted, nor does it have external storage.

Comment: I don't think non-rooted Android would get you anywhere. See https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214229/96277

Comment: I/O overhead is usually not the reason of lagging on devices using flash storage. On Android devices it's mostly a bug in the display HAL or the foreground app (be it a user app or the OS itself; the SystemUI app) which blocks the main UI thread. Logcat can be more helpful in this case. Otherwise tracing apps activities isn't possible without root as Firelord mentioned.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thanks. I notice it the most if I launch Google Play store shortly after turning on the device.  Any tips to resolve that particular issue (besides never use Google Play apps... which is tempting!)?

Comment: As I said, logcat is the first thing you should see to figure out what's going on in the background when the UI hangs. That may lead to a conclusion, and possibly the solution.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thanks... I'll capture some logs and take a look.  Do you have a favorite logcat app?  I haven't needed to logcat in so long that I can't recall what I previously used.

Comment: No sorry. I never used an app to get logcat.