# Name and type of virus on Android which is attacking file system and storage drives

Tags: file-system, storage, malware

There's a virus on my Android phone which is attacking the file systems and storage drives attached to my device.

I need help identifying the virus, so that I may further my research and come up with a solution to the problem.

Below is a list of symptoms that the virus is afflicting to my device:

- It appears to be filling my storage drives with fake, unacceptable data. The Android system is notifying me that I'm running out of data storage, yet when I check my drives, the actual data there is barely consuming a 1/10th of what storage space is available.
- The Android system at times seems slower and less responsive.
- Applications have limited to no ability to write to my storage devices, because I can't identify and remove the fake data. Disk cleaning is inefficient,  and the fake data returns like cancer.

Please help me identify the virus which is attacking my Android phone, and feel free asking me any questions regarding my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Lack of knowledge is the worst virus :) Here are some resources to educate yourself on the subject: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526) and [How to identify the app/process which re-mounts partitions R/W, creates files and changes file permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214284/218526)

Comment: Thank you, it's all about understanding the problem.

Comment: I did a bit of research and realized that what I can see in my data directory is only one of six partitions. The data that's overfilling my main storage drive may be in the other partitions that require root access to view.

Comment: Reference regarding Android File System: https://www-androidauthority-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/www.androidauthority.com/phone-storage-folders-explained-744100/?amp_js_v=a6&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQHKAFQArABIA%3D%3D#aoh=16219853243732&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidauthority.com%2Fphone-storage-folders-explained-744100%2F

Comment: Android devices usually have a few dozens of partitions, not 6: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/info-android-device-partitions-and-filesystems.3586565/. But major space is occupied by `/data`, `/system`, `/vendor` etc.